# difference query between two tables in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgresql I have table of `items` as follow:

```
id  qty 
1    20
2    45
3    10
```

it contains the quantity of each product.
I'm doing a counting operation. For every item I count I copy the data to a a `log_count` table.  Items table NEVER CHANGED.

I want to write a query which will show me the difference between the tables. Basically how much left to pass over. When the quantity is 0 the row disappears.

This is how it should be:

**Start**:

```
items:             log_count:              QUERY SHOW:
    1    20                                1        20
    2    45                                2        45
    3    10                                3        10
```

after doing count of: `id=1 qty=3`

```
items:             log_count:              QUERY SHOW:
    1    20         1      3               1        17
    2    45                                2        45
    3    10                                3        10
```

later, after doing count of: `id=2 qty=45`

```
items:             log_count:              QUERY SHOW:
    1    20         1      3               1        17
    2    45         2      45              3        10
    3    10                                * row of id 2 is gone as its qty=0
```

later, after doing count of: `id=1 qty=2`

```
items:             log_count:              QUERY SHOW:
    1    20         1      5               1        15
    2    45         2      45              3        10
    3    10
```

**Final stage...**

```
items:             log_count:              QUERY SHOW:
    1    20         1      20             
    2    45         2      45             
    3    10         3      10
```

How do I write this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple join to me:

```
select it.id, it.qty - lc.qty as difference
from items it
  left join log_count lc on it.id = lc.id 
where it.qty - lc.qty > 0;
```

Comment: can you explain why left join?

Comment: Because your fourth sample data has no row for id=3 in `log_count` but you still want to see it in the output. If the query was using an inner join, only rows would show up that _do_ have a row in `log_count`

Comment: but the join is with items . there can not be id in log_count which doesn't exists in items....

Comment: Then your sample data is wrong. Only in the last sample data, you have the same number of rows in both tables. All other examples have _fewer_ rows in `log_count` than `items`. If you are certain that **all** ids from `items` are **always** present in `log_count` then obviously the outer join is not needed.